# Using jqGrid with WCF WebAPI

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, wcf-web-api

I'm using the [wcf webapi](http://wcf.codeplex.com/) to get data from my asp.net application, and trying to display it with jqGrid. The data comes back looking like:

```
[{"DriverIdentifier":"I61","ScoreImpact":22},{"DriverIdentifier":"E57","ScoreImpact":21},{"DriverIdentifier":"K63","ScoreImpact":14}]
```

In the header I have:

```
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#driverScoreCard").jqGrid({
            url: 'api/ClientCenter',
            datatype: 'json',
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                id: 'DriverIdentifier',
                root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                rows: function (obj) { return obj; },
                page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
            },
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Driver Identifier', 'Score Impact'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'DriverIdentifier', index: 'DriverIdentifier', width: 100 },
                { name: 'ScoreImpact', index: 'ScoreImpact', width: 100 }
            ],
            pager: $('#pager'),
            caption: 'Some Grid'
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

And down in the page, I have the following elements:

<table id="driverScoreCard"><tr><td></td></tr></table><div id="pager"></div>

When running the example, I get "Object doesn't support property or method 'format'" in the jqGrid source. I'm using version 4.1.2 of jqGrid. Let me know if I can provide any more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change the order of the `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` file and `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and all will be OK: see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TimHoolihan.htm)